# need to detect value change in text box on blur event in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a scenario where a page consists several text boxes. In that some are having default values and some are empty. In this context i need to validate the text boxes which are having default values. No need to validate textboxes with empty values

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result,use below option

```
$('input').blur(function() {
  $(this).each(
    function(index) {
      var input = $(this);
      alert('Input Name: ' + input.attr('id') + ' field should not be empty');
    }
  )
});
```

codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzLRXP

Comment: Intentionally left first field blank for testing and console log returns all the input fields with default values.Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Hi Nagasai, here i need the functionality that if user empties the textbox with value, then put an alert to user "field should not be empty" and focus on that text box until user enters some numeric value

Comment: Updated code pen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzLRXP  check it once now

Comment: I think i haven't asked properly. sorry for that. Let me explain clearly. For example, there are three textboxes in a page. tb1,tb2,tb3. assume tb1 is empty and tb2 & tb3 are having some numeric values by default. tb1 should not be validated. tb2 & tb3 on blur, check if text box is empty or not if empty then put alert. else validate textbox whether value is numeric or not. This is situation

Comment: Modified the script to meet that requirement..Hope this time works for you :)

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzLRXP